# Azure 502 web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway

Tags: azure

I started getting random 502 errors on my page. Is this connected with Azure or my website? I didn't do any changes since Thursday, so I am little skeptical about being my code.

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

I was checking the logs, but all it says is at which url it happens, and it happens on main root page.

Comment: Oh no, same here. I wonder if it's Azure then?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened because of an infinite loop in the code, which was only triggered in production but not on my local machine. Fixing the infinite loop obviously fixed the 502. ;-)

*Update:* Meta-example of the infinite loop (C#).

```csharp
public IList<Model> PropertyOne
{
    get
    {
        return !_productionOnlyCondition ? _models.ToList() : PropertyTwo;
    }
}

public IList<Model> PropertyTwo
{
    get
    {
        return PropertyOne.Where(model => model.Condition).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give example of infinite loop you did?